# Determine whether point is inside transformed matrix

Tags: java, android, matrix

Consider the following example:

[image: Matrix transformation]

The blue pane is an `ImageView`, the red pane is the actual visible image/bitmap.
With `setImageMatrix` a matrix transform is set, resulting in the red square on the right (which is translated, scaled and rotated).

In the `onTouch` method of the `ImageView`'s `OnTouchListener` I want to determine whether the touch happened inside the red square or not. How is this done?

Comment: Multiply the vector formed by the mouse coordinates with the inverse of the transformation matrix and see if the result would have been in the original red square (i.e. before you transformed it).

Comment: see how i did it in https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable/blob/master/PatchworkDrawableLibrary/src/org/pskink/patchworkdrawable/drawable/PatchworkDrawable.java , method getLayersAt

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try that! The 'vector formed by the mouse coordinates' is from (0,0) to (mouseX, mouseY), right?

Comment: @pskink I'm going to check that out as well!

Comment: @T.S. so you have a working solution, and i mean it: it works

Comment: @T.S. all you need is to call mapPoints with. one x,y point, see my code

Comment: If one of you turns their comment into an answer I will accept it. Otherwise I'll except my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of chris' pointer and pskink's example code I got to the following:

```
/**
 * Transformation matrix used to transform the image
 */
private Matrix transformationM;

/**
 * Matrix that is used in calculations (inverse of tranformation matrix)
 */
private Matrix tmpM;

/**
 * Checks whether a point is on the transformed image
 */
public boolean pointIsOnImage(float x, float y) {
    // Float array that will hold the mapped point (see 'mapPoints' below)
    float[] p1 = {0, 0};

    // Float array that holds the touch position
    final float[] p2 = {x, y};

    // Reset temporary matrix
    tmpM.reset();

    // Get the inverse matrix of the current transformation matrix and store it in the temporary matrix
    transformationM.invert(tmpM);

    // Map the touch position on the inverse matrix
    tmpM.mapPoints(p1, 0, p2, 0, 1);

    // Check if touch position is in the drawable bounds
    return getDrawable().getBounds().contains((int) p1[0], (int) p1[1]);
}
```

The reason I can call `getDrawable()` this way is because I'm using this code inside a class which extends `ImageView`. You could use this code anywhere if you make the drawable part of the method arguments.

Comment: in your case you can use mapPoints with two float[] params (or even one)

Comment: btw arent you doing something similar to mine PatchworkDrawable (the link i posted in the first omment) ?

Comment: Yes, it's small part of the project I'm working on, but I certainly would have used your library if I had known about it beforehand!

Comment: if you want your Drawables not only to be  transformed by a Matrix but also animated by any android Animation you can see how. i did did,  its just a dozen lines or so